# Changes to imported makefile don't trigger rebuild in android-ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk, makefile, android-ndk-r7

I have an Android JNI project I'd like to compile with `ndk-build`. The project contains of multiple third-party sub projects.

```
+- jni
   +- Android.mk
   +- my-proj.mk
   +- other-proj.mk
   +- my-proj
      +- a.cpp
      +- b.cpp
   +- other-proj  (third-party)
      +- c.cpp
      +- d.cpp
```

The idea now is to include/import the makefiles of all sub projects in `Android.mk`, like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(LOCAL_PATH)/my-proj.mk
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/other-proj.mk
```

`other-proj` is built as *static* library. `my-proj.mk` depends on `other-proj` and is built as *shared* library.

Building this project works. **However, modifying either `my-proj.mk` or `other-proj.mk` doesn't trigger a rebuild of the respective project.** Is there a way to do this?

I though I could list the makefiles as dependencies of `Android.mk` but I couldn't figure out a way. (Listing them under `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` doesn't work.)

I also read about `$(call import-module,foo/bar)` which seems to do exactly what I want. However, in this case I had to place the makefiles in a directory *adjacent* to the project directories (e.g. `jni/makefiles/other-proj/Android.mk`) but I couldn't figure out how to specify the `LOCAL_SRC_FILES`. They don't seem to like to be specified with an absolute path or with a `..` inside the path. (I can't place the makefiles directly in the sub project directories as they're third-party projects.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Depend on the make file itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150830/depend-on-the-make-file-itself)

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate. The Android makefiles behave slightly different than regular makefiles. For example, editing an Android makefile will rebuild all source files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a way to do it, although not with simple includes but rather with `$(call import-module,foo/bar)`.

First change, you need to decide on one of the sub projects being the main project. Let's take `my-proj` for that. Then the directory structure changes like this:

```
+- jni
   +- Android.mk
   +- my-proj
      +- a.cpp
      +- b.cpp
   +- other-proj  (third-party)
      +- Android.mk
      +- c.cpp
      +- d.cpp
```

Basically I renamed `my-proj.mk` to `/Android.mk` and `other-proj.mk` to `other-proj/Android.mk`.

The main `Android.mk` then changes to something like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
...
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := other-proj
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH))
$(call import-module,other-proj)
```

The `other-proj` is included in the last line.

Note that the line before the last line sets the module path. Setting the module path from *within* the makefile via

```
NDK_MODULE_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)
```

does **not** work. (If `NDK_MODULE_PATH` is to be used, it needs to be defined as an environment variable outside of the makefile).

Answer (score 1):

It might not be the most elegant way, but sometimes I modify one of the sources by putting in an extra space or a new line.  That seems to wake the compiler up.

Comment: Yeah, but only for this source file. I doesn't trigger the whole Makefile (= project) being rebuilt.