# How to force make to run clean target if makefile changed

Tags: makefile

If *makefile* changes, make rebuilds all targets right?

But how to tell **make** that if after *makefile* changed, it shall run `make clean` and then `make`?

Or how to instruct make to run some other command in that situation? Do I have to write a special kind of target?

Comment: Are you using GNU make only, or are you using another make program?

Comment: It's not true that make rebuilds after a change to the makefile - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871444/making-all-rules-depend-on-the-makefile-itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you want to run clean automatically because you want certain targets to be rebuilt whenever make is called. This can be achieved by adding  a dependency named `FORCE` to the rule whose target you want to build always and then define `FORCE` like this: ie no rule and no dependency.

```
FORCE:
```

Please see http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Force-Targets

If you want all files to be recompiled, you add the following to the makefile:

```
%.o : %.cpp FORCE
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Answer (score 4):

You *could* try this:

```
all: Makefile.uptodate yourMainTarget

Makefile.uptodate: Makefile
    make clean
    touch Makefile.uptodate
```

I'm not a `make` expert so I don't know if that's a horrible hack, but it worked in my limited tests ;-)

Comment: This will break for parallel builds (with `-j`), as it may run `make clean` at the same time as it is building for `yourMainTarget`.

Comment: ^ "This will break for parallel builds" Correct. To fix, add a dependency to `yourMainTarget` like so: `yourMainTarget: Makefile.uptodate <the rest of your dependencies>`. Then also add it in a similar fashion to all other targets, e.g. `.o` files for compiling C/C++ code or something. This will force it to resolve the commands under the `Makefile.uptodate` target before starting the build of `yourMainTarget` or any of its dependencies, which allows the clean to finish before e.g. compiling anything or running anything.

Answer (score 4):

Crude but effective (I can't think of anything more elegant):

```
include marker

marker: Makefile
    @touch $@
    $(MAKE) clean
    $(MAKE)
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `$(MAKE)` at the end; that should be handled by the initial entry of the Makefile. Right? Clever using `include` though!