# Consider makefile out of date if include updated, only if it exists

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Consider the following Makefile which knows to clean and rebuild itself if the Makefile or its included configuration files `config.mk` or `local.mk` are changed:

```
include config.mk
-include local.mk

-include dummy.rebuild

all: ...
# other targets...

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/3892826/149138
dummy.rebuild: Makefile config.mk local.mk
    touch $@
    $(MAKE) -s clean
```

This works fine if `config.mk` and `local.mk` actually exist - if either is modified, the `dummy.rebuild` target fires and the project is rebuild.

However, imagine that `local.mk` is an optional file which may or may not exist. In the case that it doesn't exist, the `dummy.rebuild` rule never seems to run at all, even if the Makefile or `config.mk` is changed. This is  different behavior than a normal rule where a dependency doesn't exist, usually you'd get an error like:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'local.mk', needed by 'dummy.rebuild'.  Stop.
```

... but in the case of the `dummy.rebuild` target implicitly added as a target via inclusion, you just get:

```
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

How can I implement the makefile so that if any of `Makefile`, `config.mk` or `local.mk` are changed, the `dummy.rebuild` target is executed, where the `local.mk` file may not exist?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but maybe using this instead will give you the behavior you want:

```
local.mk := $(wildcard local.mk)

include $(local.mk)
  ...
dummy.rebuild: Makefile config.mk $(local.mk)
  ...
```

Using `wildcard` here expands to `local.mk` if the file exists, or the empty string if it doesn't exist so it will be ignored in all ways if it's not there.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I've settled on so far.